# Import cells without strikeout from xlsx

Tags: r, xlconnect, r-xlsx

I'm trying to import an excel file avoiding cell that have a strikeout as style, but I'm not sure of how to do it.

I know that in the library `XLConnect` there is a function `getCellStyle` but I cannot find much documentation on how to use it with a strikethroug/strikeout and I would like to avoid that library because sometimes it gives me problems when the workbook is big.

Comment: Is strikeout the same as strikethrough? And would you like to disregard the style altogether or do you need to know if a number had a strikethrough?

Comment: @ekstroem yes, it's the same thing, I have found it referenced in different way. I need to exclude all rows with a strikethrough when I import the excel file into a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem:

1. I have a VBA macro to remove the strikethrough and that iterates through all the sheets. Code available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362873/delete-strikethrough-cells-and-iterate-through-all-sheets)
2. I embedded the first macro into another one that applies the changes to all files in a folder that the user can select (you can skip this step if you need it just for one file). Code available [here](https://www.google.se/search?q=iterate%20through%20files%20in%20a%20folder%20vba&oq=iterates%20through%20files%20in%20a%20folder%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.12710j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
3. I call the macro from R. Code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367616/calling-vba-macro-from-r).