# Calling VBA macro from R

Tags: r, vba

I'm trying to call a macro from R, and I have followed the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404270/run-vba-script-from-r) question but I het an error:

```
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
Error: Exception occurred.
```

My code is the following:

```
library(RDCOMClient)

# Open a specific workbook in Excel:
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("Y:\\macroR.xlsm")

# this line of code might be necessary if you want to see your spreadsheet:
xlApp[['Visible']] <- FALSE 

# Run the macro called "MyMacro":
xlApp$Run("LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder")

# Close the workbook and quit the app:
xlWbk$Close(FALSE)
xlApp$Quit()

# Release resources:
rm(xlWbk, xlApp)
```

The macro is supposed to remove all the strikethrough cells in all the worksheets in all workbooks contained in a folder selected by the user. I can share the code if it is relevant.

Comment: which line crashes ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  it's the line xlApp$Run

Comment: Have you tried to run it on an empty macro ?

Comment: My suspicion is that your xlApp isnt fully qualifying which workbook to look in for the macro it needs to fun. I dont know the code for it in R, but in VBA it would be something like `Application.Run(TargetWorkbook.FullName &"!"&"MacroName")`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney that was indeed the problem, the code in R is Workbookname.MacroName, where the workbook name is the one that you get in the macro view, so likely MyWorkbook.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper no I had not tried that but the problem was actually the name without the reference to the workbook.